# Dynamically made flat file connection - want to take most recent file in the folder using SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have created one SSIS package that takes .csv file data and insert into SQL table,

But now I want most recently added file in that folder suppose

My flat file connection path is : `C:\Temp`

Now in temp there is my file named `MYDATA 2011-09-08.csv`

now some more files are there like `MYDATA 2011-09-15.csv` , `MYDATA 2011-09-17.csv`

Now `MYDATA 2011-09-17.csv` is the most recent by date and i want to pickup this file how can i do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would complete this task with a foreach loop combined with a script task.

- First you should declare 3 variables:

[image: Variables]

- Next step is adding a foreach loop container to the package with a script component inside of it.

[image]

- Set foreach loop container properties as follows.

[image]

[image]

- Set variables which script component has access to

[image]

- In the script component parse the date from the file name, check if it greater than the recent date (`User::RecentDate`), and if it is save it to the `User::RecentFileName` variable.

  ```
  string strDatePart = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
      Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString()).Substring(7);
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
  if (DateTime.TryParse(strDatePart, out dateTime))
  {
      if (dateTime > (DateTime)Dts.Variables["User::RecentDate"].Value)
      {
          Dts.Variables["User::RecentDate"].Value = dateTime;
          Dts.Variables["User::RecentFileName"].Value =           
              Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value;
      }

      Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
  }
  else
      Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
  ```

Of course you can change this script as you wish it's just an example. After the loop ends the `User::RecentFileName` will contain your desired result.